# Control flow for a webservice-backed iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm learning the basics of iOS development, and I'd like to make a simple application that connects to a web service. I've got a lot of experience on the web application side, so I'm comfortable with what kinds of requests the app needs to send/receive etc. The part I'm not sure about is what the big picture architecture of a service-backed mobile application looks like.

When my application runs, I have one major requirement: the user must authenticate into the web service. The web service can send back a token and the app can use this for all subsequent requests. I want the user to be able to log in once, and for the app to stay logged in (ie the token remains valid for that device) indefinitely unless they log out.

Until the user logs in the application should really just be a login screen. If they log out, the same. Otherwise, they don't need to see the login screen at all.

So my question is, what is the right way to structure this?

In `AppDelegate`, do I want to make a `LoginViewController` and set it to the `rootViewController`? Then if the user is logged in, push to the main view for the rest of the app?

Or do I want to initialize the main part of the app (for instance, a `UITabBarController` with a few views in it), and check for a token, and then display a modal login screen if no token is available?

What I'm not clear on is what the `rootViewController` should be for an application like this, and how the app should keep track of whether the user is logged in, and determine what screen to show when the app is opened.

If anyone can give me a high level overview of how such an app should be structured, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a right way to do this, either flow could be appropriate for an application. If I had some UI or data that would be displayed if a user is not logged in then I would use that as the initial rootViewController and use a modal login dialog to force the user to login. On the other hand, if I had nothing to display until a user has logged in then I would setup the login view controller to be the initial rootViewController if the user is not currently logged in.

For keeping track of the user being logged in you should leverage NSUserDefaults to persist the authentication token. Then in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: call to your app delegate look for this token in NSUserDefaults (and possibly validate it with the server) then set the rootViewController as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Cory - I'm so new at iOS I didn't know about NSUserDefaults yet, that was very helpful!